# Test for HTTP 405 Not allowed

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, google-app-engine, webtest

Im setting up a project with Google App Engine in python.

At the moment it just looks like this

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('Hello World!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Im trying to learn how to work the TDD way, so i tested the `get` following [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) example by Google.

It has this test case

```
def test_MainPage_get(self):
    response = self.testapp.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 200)
```

That works great and returns 200 as expected. Then i figured i should test `post` as well. I tried to test it like this

```
def test_MainPage_post(self):
    response = self.testapp.post('/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 405)
```

Because post is not implemented i expect it to return status 405 and the test case to report success. However the console shows this and quits

```
The method POST is not allowed for this resouce.

------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Why does it stop there and not return the 405 to my test case? Am i doing it wrong? Is there an other(better) way to test for `method not allowed` codes?

Comment: This is, presumably, using [WebTest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: @Martijn Yes, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [exception is being raised](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/testapp.html#what-is-tested-by-default) for any response that is not a 2xx or 3xx status code.

You assert that it is being raised instead:

```
def test_MainPage_post(self):
    with self.assertRaises(webtest.AppError) as exc:
        response = self.testapp.post('/')

    self.assertTrue(str(exc).startswith('Bad response: 405')
```

Alternatively, set `expect_errors` to `True`:

```
def test_MainPage_post(self):
    response = self.testapp.post('/', expect_errors=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 405)
```

or tell the `post` method to expect a 405:

```
def test_MainPage_post(self):
    response = self.testapp.post('/', status=405)
```

where `AppError` would be raised if the response status was not a 405. `status` here can be a list or tuple of statuses as well.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I used your 2nd suggestion because it fits my current code better and it works

Comment: @TimCastelijns: added one more option for you there.